# PostGIS/pgrouting pgr_createTopology return an empty table

Tags: pgrouting

I am new of Pgrouting, I have created a new database with PostGIS and PgRouting extension, than I have populated my DB using the osm2po sotware and now I have my graphs. However I need to create the vertices table in order to make the network routable, I run the following command:

`SELECT pgr_createTopology('grafo_padova', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'id');`

Postgres returns

NOTIFICA:  PROCESSING:
NOTIFICA:  pgr_createTopology('grafo_padova', 1e-005, 'the_geom', 'id', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean := f)
NOTIFICA:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTIFICA:  Creating Topology, Please wait...
NOTIFICA:  -------------> TOPOLOGY CREATED FOR  0 edges
NOTIFICA:  Rows with NULL geometry or NULL id: 0
NOTIFICA:  Vertices table for table public.grafo_padova is: public.grafo_padova_vertices_pgr
NOTIFICA:  ----------------------------------------------

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 77 msec.
1 rows affected.

And the result is an empty table. The table "grafo_padova" has a geometry column named "the_geom" and it is filled.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure, that `id` and `the_geom` attribute exist?

However, if you already have the topology computed with osm2po, then you can just run `pgr_createVerticesTable` function to add the vertices table: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.4/en/pgr_createVerticesTable.html#pgr-create-vert-table

Comment: Thanks a lot, using pgr_createVerticesTable everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Recreating topology without cleaning up won't make sense and you will get an empty pgr table.

Set method parameter `clean = true` if you had created topology on the edge table before.

https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgr_createTopology.html